# How can a junior in high school start preparing for the Putnam?

Tags: contest-math

I am a junior in high school and I have a keen interest in math. I've already completed AP Calculus BC (which is equivalent to Calculus II in college) and am self-studying topics like multivariable calculus and linear algebra. I'm probably going to double major in math and physics. I plan to take the Putnam when I enter college.
My question is, how can I, at this early stage, cultivate the mathematical dexterity and flexibility that are necessary for a difficult math competition like Putnam? Are there any resources, like textbooks and online materials, that I can use to train myself in this respect? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prepare for Putnam is to do past papers! Find a past paper, go through questions; when you see something you don't understand, look it up. You'll quickly amass a large amount of knowledge and be able to cover all the topics covered in Putnam, as well as the problem solving methods employed.